# PHP/MySql Update query Is Not Working

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I update anything in my admin panel and click on update button then nothing happens — i.e it neither updates it nor goes to the page from where we click edit. I am using free hosting. The same code is working on the local host, but it is not working on free hosting. Can anyone help me?

```
$sqlN="UPDATE selectplan SET plan_name='$planname',Plandetails='$Plandetails', Plantime='$Plantime', Plandate='$Plandate', plancost='$plancost', img='$image' WHERE id='$id__' ;";
$resultN=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlN);
```

Here is the complete code

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header('Location:index.php');
}   
else
{
    $id__=$_GET['id'];

    $sql="SELECT * from selectplan where id='$id__' ;";

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if((mysqli_num_rows($result))>0)
    {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        $id_P=$row[0]; //id
        $planname=$row[1];//name
        $Plandetails=$row[2];
        $Plantime=$row[3];
        $Plandate=$row[4];
        $plancost=$row[5];
        $img__=$row[6];
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $planname=$_POST["planname"];//name
    $Plandetails=$_POST["Plandetails"];
    $Plantime=$_POST["Plantime"];
    $Plandate=$_POST["Plandate"];
    $plancost=$_POST["plancost"];
    if($planname==""||$Plandetails==""||$Plantime==""||$Plandate==""||$plancost=="")
    {
        echo "Please fill in all the fields";
    }
    else
    {
        $target="images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name'] );

        //get all the submitted data from the form
        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

        //now move upload image to folder
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target))
        {
            echo "image upload";
        }
        $sqlN="UPDATE selectplan SET plan_name='$planname',Plandetails='$Plandetails', Plantime='$Plantime', Plandate='$Plandate', plancost='$plancost', img='$image' WHERE id='$id__' ;";
        $resultN=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlN);
        if ($resultN) {
            header('Location:profile.php');
        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit Plan</title>
</head>
<body class="t">
<p><a href="userlist.php">Back to Profile</a>
||
<a href="logout.php">Logout Now</a></p>
<br> <br><br> 
    <form action="profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        Plan Name:<br><textarea name="planname" id="" value="" cols="80" ><?php echo $planname;  ?></textarea><br>
        Plan Details:<br><textarea name="Plandetails" id="" value="" cols="80" rows="6"><?php echo $Plandetails;  ?></textarea><br>
        Plan Time:<br><input type="time" name="Plantime" id="" value="<?php echo $Plantime;   ?>" /><br>
        Plan Date:<br><input type="date" name="Plandate" id="" value="<?php echo $Plandate; ?>" /><br><br>
        Plan Cost:<br><input type="numbers" name="plancost" id="" value="<?php echo $plancost; ?>" /><br><br>
        Image:<br><?php echo "<img src='images/$img__'"; ?> alt="Tourism" height="150" width="300" > <br><input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000"><input type="file" name="image"  /><br></br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update now ">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on php and mysql error checking?

Comment: not a single error message? is your form being submitted?

Comment: Add the following two lines to the start of your script: ```error_reporting(E_ALL);```   ```ini_set('display_errors', '1');```

Comment: @salonthrasher no I haven't tried that

Comment: @leo_ap no not a single error message. And the form is not being submitted. As no changes applies to the given data.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is in conn.php 
your auth values is incorrect 
in conn.php  yku should change the value that is currently localhost and change the user and pass